# Data Source - Melhor forma de organizar métodos/classes pertinentes à tabela inteira?

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, asp

Na minha empresa nós trabalhamos com modelos baseados no padrão "Active Record", ou seja, os métodos do modelo são sempre referentes as operações de um registro unico do banco de dados, por exemplo:

```
Class User {
    int id;
    string Name;

    public Find (id); // SQL / ORM to return the object based on the user's Id;
    public Save (); // SQL / ORM to save / update a user
    public Delete (); // SQL / ORM to delete a user.
}

// Create the user "John"
Set objUser = new User ();
objUser.Name = "John";
objUser.Save ();
```

A minha dúvida é a seguinte, em relação à entidade do banco de dados "User", temos métodos que são à nivel de tabela e não de registro, como por exemplo um método "getAllActiveUsers", que me retorna um objeto de consulta de todos os usuários ativos. 
Esse tipo de situação hoje, por uma falta de padrão acaba ficando no proprio modelo ActiveRecord, o que na minha opinião não faz muito sentido.. Vocês poderiam me indicar o que seria o mais recomendavel/elegante para tratar este tipo de situação? 
Li alguma coisa sobre Gateway e Repository Pattern que talvez sejam uteis para isso, mas queria saber se alguem já teve este mesmo dilema e como fez para resolver..

Obrigado e desculpem pela ignorância!

Answer (score 1):

Na minha opinião não faz sentido o próprio objeto "se salvar" no banco de dados, independente se você utiliza ADO puro ou algum ORM, creio que o padrão Repository seja mais apropriado; mas claro que tudo dependo do cenário.

Recomendo que veja este tutorial do Eduardo Pires, ele faz um passo a passo e explica alguns padrões e como implementa-los, talvez não seja a solução de todos seus problemas, mas você começará a ter uma nova visão e à partir daí pensar em sua própria arquitetura:

http://eduardopires.net.br/2014/10/tutorial-asp-net-mvc-5-ddd-ef-automapper-ioc-dicas-e-truques/

Espero ter ajudado.